# press any key exit not working properly

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener

I have written the following code, Please check it:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Example{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello StackOverflow");
        System.out.println("Press any key to exit");
       try{        
        getCh();        
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Error"+e);
        }

    }

    public static void getCh() {  
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();  
        synchronized (frame) {  
            frame.setUndecorated(true);  
            frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);  
            frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {  
                    synchronized (frame) {  
                        frame.setVisible(false);  
                        frame.dispose();  
                        frame.notify();  
                    }  
                }  
                @Override 
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {  
                }  
                @Override 
                public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {  
                }  
            });  
            frame.setVisible(true);  
            try {  
                frame.wait();  
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {  
            }  
        }  
    }
}
```

It is working partially, but not working properly. I need to exit on any key press after printing **`Hello StackOverflow`**. Please guide me guys. I need a simple program. This code looks so lengthy and have heavy components such as Swing. Please help guys!!

Comment: I think you can use `System.exit(0)` .

Comment: @Mayank it wont make any change in this!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello StackOverflow");
        System.out.println("Press any key to exit");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = scanner.nextInt();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `nextInt`? Did you mean `scanner` instead of `ItemSelect`?

Comment: `scanner` is an object, you can name it anything you want

Comment: Thanks, cap! You're just getting `ItemSelect` where it's not declared.

Comment: @Mayank ItemSelect cannot find symbol, which should be imported!!

Comment: @Mayank not worked!!Getting error as I mentioned above@@

Comment: what issue you are facing ?